# "An error was found. Do you want to resend it?"

Tags: kde, bug-reporting

When I logged in to my machine running Kubuntu 14.04 this evening, the following message popped up:

[image]

If I were running Windows, I would immediately shut down the system, change my passwords, and get my backups ready. But since this is Linux, it's probably not a virus, so I checked it out. Apparently, the process running the window is `akonadi_sendlater_agent`.

What error happened that I or any developer would care about? Was anything sent and can I see the error?

Comment: See the errors in /var/crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I queued a message to be sent in KMail and shut the machine down before it was scheduled to send. The message was asking whether or not I wanted to resend the email.